# Customize appearance of react-jsonschema-form

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm Have a simple app with the following index.js code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

import Form from "react-jsonschema-form";

const schema = {
  "title": "A registration form",
  "description": "A simple form example.",
  "type": "object",
  "required": [
    "firstName",
    "lastName"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "firstName": {
      "type": "string",
      "title": "First name",
      "default": ""
    },
    "telephone": {
      "type": "string",
      "title": "Telephone",
      "minLength": 10
    }
  }
}

const log = type => console.log.bind(console, type);

render(
  <Form
    schema={schema}
    autocomplete="on"
    onChange={log("changed")}
    onSubmit={log("submitted")}
    onError={log("errors")}
  />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

The example does generates the form but its appearance is not eye-catching:

[image]

I'm comparing this with the forms shown in the [live-demo](https://rjsf-team.github.io/react-jsonschema-form/) and its appearance is much more appealing :

[image]

How can I change this? In the demo I don't see any additional CSS code or template to do this

Comment: Have you followed the same installation process [https://react-jsonschema-form.readthedocs.io/en/latest/](https://react-jsonschema-form.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) ?

Comment: @NiteshSharma could a different installation process of the same library lead to different results? I'm new on react and JS, but have not heard of this on other language

Comment: yes it is possible, try to follow the mentioned steps in the link and also if that doesn't work try to add bootstrap in your react component as this library work with bootstrap

Comment: @NiteshSharma it was because Boostrap, if you put the instructions to install an import it  in index.js I'll accept the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to install bootstrap as the document says library works with bootstrap you can follow below steps to install for your setup:

1. node install bootstrap --global
2. add `import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';`
   in your app.js

I hope it will work.